# Can I package Flash built Android application with Air runtime environment?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I am engaged in a game project which using ActionScript3 as language and Flash Builder 4.6 as IDE. Everything works good. But Android have to install Air runtime environment firstly which is not very convironment I think. So I wonder if we have a method to package app with Air runtime environment? For example, can we made a Android install application which includes both my game and Air?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do that (and this is what done automatically every time you package for iOS). All you need to do is change target from "apk-*something*" to "apk-captive-runtime".

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader

*My personal recommendation though is to upload to market two versions of app with and without embedded runtime. Because some people simply don't need that embedded runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this very easily with Flash Builder 4.6.

What you are looking for is to create application package with captive AIR runtime. This includes AIR runtime into your instalation package. Flash builder 4.6 supports this feature. It is quite simple, just change option to captive when you export release build.

Look at this link to tell you how exactly to do that.
http://www.grindheadgames.com/captive-runtime

It should be noted, that captive runtime makes your application to take about 20mb of space after installation (installation package is about 9mb of size)